# how to enable/disable directory browsing Red5 app

Tags: streaming, jetty, red5

I have developed red5 app. How do I enable/disable directory browsing for the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Open the config file : /conf/web.xml and modify the part related to "listings" :

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

By default the param-value was set to **true** on my instance. Changing it to false did the trick.

**Important note** : You need to restart Red5 for the changes to take effect.